# Why am I recieving this error: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Films'

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm trying to get PrimeNG to work in my app but I ran into an error that I can't find a solution to fix.

I want to create a delete function with confirmationDialog.

here is the code from my component.ts file:

```
export interface Films {
  id?: any;
  nameOfFilm?: string;
  length?: string;
  director?: string;
}

// ...


 deleteFilm(film: Films) {
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: 'Are you sure you want to delete ' + film.nameOfFilm + '?',
      header: 'Confirm',
      icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
      accept: () => {
        this.films = this.films.filter(val => val.id !== film.id);  // error is here on filter
        this.film = {};
        this.messageService.add({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Successful', detail: 'Product Deleted', life: 3000 });
      }
    });
  }
```

This is the error:

```
Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Films'.
```

and

```
 Parameter 'val' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because `filter` is a method of the prototype of `array` and `films` is of type `Films` , and not, say, `Film[]` . It is not possible to suggest a better solution without seeing the rest of the code, specifically the details of the `Films` class.

Comment: added details for ```Films```

Comment: The assignment of your films property at line:
  this.films = this.films.filter(val => val.id !== film.id); 
should be defined as the following in the outer scope of your component
files:Films[]=[];

Comment: Then, the name of the interface should be Film, not Films (because it represent a single Film, with a name, director, etc.) and the type of `this.films` should be Film[] and you should not change the collection when you filter it.

Comment: where is the initialization of `this.films` ?